# Problema con configuración de build.gradle proyecto Java con Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, build.gradle

tengo un problema al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto de Java con Selenium, cuando estoy configurando lo necesario para las dependencias en el build.gradle reimporto y en la terminal me sale logs de error, este es mi build.gralde

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.9.9")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'
compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
dependencies {
    testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.1.1'
    testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.1.1'
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    testCompile('org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0')
    testCompile('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7')
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.9.9'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.9.9'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:1.9.5'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:1.9.9'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:1.9.9'
}
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

el error es el siguiente:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'proyectoBaseScreenPlay'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.9.9.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.9.9.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/serenity-bdd/serenity-gradle-plugin/1.9.9/serenity-gradle-plugin-1.9.9.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/serenity-bdd/serenity-gradle-plugin/1.9.9/serenity-gradle-plugin-1.9.9.pom'.
               > proxycelta1.proteccion.local
```

ya intente cambiando en dependencies el classpath la version por diferentes, pero es indiferente, el error sale con cualquier de las versiones que se ponga.

agradecería su ayuda!

Comment: ¿Estás detrás de un proxy? ¿Si pruebas desde una red que esté fuera del proxy te funciona? Por ejemplo probando en un portátil compartiéndote la wifi con el móvil

Comment: ya lo hice pero sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema, me conecte desde la red de un movil, y salen los mismos logs